# Is it bad practice to mix templates and runtime polymorphism and are there any alternatives?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I am trying to link an enum value to some class object so that I can manipulate the object by only using the enum value. I initially wanted to use a templated approach for learning purposes and the fact it would allow some compile-time computations.

After the initial implementation I've found myself in a situation where it seems like I need some sort of runtime code as well and I'm backtracking on the entire approach thinking that templating it is useless as I could achieve exactly the same thing with less obscure code just using polymorphism alone albeit introducing some call overhead.

```
enum Fruit { 
    All, 
    Orange, 
    Banana, 
    Mango
};
static const int FRUIT_COUNT = 4;

class BasketBase
{
public:

    int m_otherFruitsBitfield; 
};

template <Fruit T = Fruit::All>
class Basket {};

template<>
class Basket<Orange> : public BasketBase
{
public:
    void Open() { printf("Basket (Oranges) - Open\n"); }

    static Basket<Orange> m_basket;
};

template<>
class Basket<Banana> : public BasketBase
{
public:
    void Open() { printf("Basket (Bananas) - Open\n"); }
    void Throw() { printf("Basket (Bananas) - Throwing"); }
    void Drop() { printf("Basket (Bananas) - Dropping"); }

    int m_numBananas;
    static Basket<Banana> m_basket;
};

Basket<Orange> Basket<Orange>::m_basket;
Basket<Banana> Basket<Banana>::m_basket;

template<Fruit T>
Basket<T>& GetBasket()
{
    return Basket<T>::m_basket;
}

template<Fruit T>
void OpenBasket()
{
    GetBasket<T>().Open();
}


int main() {

  OpenBasket<Orange>();
  OpenBasket<Banana>();

  GetBasket<Orange>().m_otherFruitsBitfield = (1 << Banana) | (1 << Mango);
  GetBasket<Banana>().m_otherFruitsBitfield = (1 << Mango);

  //opening the basket should now open every other basket in the bitfield
  int orangeBitfield = GetBasket<Orange>().m_otherFruitsBitfield;

    for (int i = 0; i < FRUIT_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        Fruit fruit = static_cast<Fruit>(i);
        if (orangeBitfield & fruit)
        {
            //OpenBasket(fruit); //runtime
            //OpenBasket<fruit>() //nope
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is a simplified version, but serves the same purpose. The aim of this was to have some sort of *shared* object (`Basket`) that would be tied to an individual enum value (`Fruit`), and client code could call into the object by passing the enum. Each `Basket` does share some common functionality, like `Open`, but outside of that is completely independent and may contain specific data to the fruit being held.

Using the above approach I was able to compute all of the bitfields/object initializing at compile-time since I knew the data upfront, however `otherFruitsBitfield` can now change at runtime which means I can't use the templated versions of `GetBasket<>()` and would need a runtime one. Same applies to another variable which stores the currently viewed basket.

To fix this, I can think to add some virtual calls to the base class and override them, but then I question what's the point in using the template? I can achieve the same thing by storing a list of `BasketBase*` and just doing everything at runtime but I would like to get out of my comfort zone regarding implementation.

Am I missing something here or is this not a valid use of a template? Could anyone provide some more information on these issues and any potential solutions?

Comment: _"...are there any alternatives?"_ Have a read about CRTP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp and also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+crtp

Comment: @RichardCritten thank you. Seems useful in some scenarios when a shared/limited interface is concerned at compile-time. I'm not sure it would be applicable for the problem I'm trying to solve though unfortunately.

Comment: It gives you the option for compile time polymorphism